# Why can't Go floats overflow but integers can?

Tags: go, overflow

I've been testing a few things in Go, and noticed integers can overflow, but `float64` and `float32` apparently can't.

```
f64 := math.MaxFloat64
fmt.Printf("%f\n", f64)
fmt.Printf("%f\n", f64+1)

f32 := math.MaxFloat32
fmt.Printf("%f\n", f32)
fmt.Printf("%f\n", f32+1)

i := math.MaxInt64
fmt.Printf("%d\n", i)
fmt.Printf("%d\n", i+1)
```

Result:

```
179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000
179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000
340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
9223372036854775807
-9223372036854775808
```

Integer overflows are apparently not checked for performance reasons, but why can't I make floats overflow? Are they checked?

Comment: To a certain degree floats do "overflow". Try e.g.  `math.Pow10(100)`. Or `math.Sqrt(-4)`. They just do not wrap around.

Comment: The precision for floats at the upper bound is nowhere near enough to represent "one more". Try doubling the numbers: https://play.golang.org/p/Ve6MO0FFHNA

Comment: Knowing the basics of IEEE-754 is essentially required knowledge for most programmers. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/32880 and see https://floating-point-gui.de/ as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the data structures are fundamentally different. The [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) structure used by most programming languages ([including Go](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)) for (at least most of) their integral data types overflows as a by-product of how it works; the [IEEE-754 floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) used by most programming languages (including Go) for (at least most of) their floating point data types doesn't overflow, the way it works the magnitude of the number just continues to increase and, once it's past a certain point, the number starts losing precision even at the integer level.

It's just that the two mechanisms for storing numeric data in a fixed-size set of bits work fundamentally differently.

There are other structures. For instance, some languages have "big integer" and/or "big decimal" types that aren't fixed size; instead, they take up however much room they need to hold the number. (Java's `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal`, JavaScript's `BigInt`, ...) Go has `Int`, `Rat`, and `Float` in the [`math/big` package](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/). *(Thanks [Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7426/adrian)!)* The fixed-size ones are very useful because they're very fast; but sometimes you want something other than speed (extended range, better precision in floating point, etc.), in which case you sacrifice some speed for the other thing you need.

Comment: In Go those types are in the [`math/big` package](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/).

Comment: @Adrian - Thanks!! I've added that to the answer and marked it CW. I should have known Go would have them somewhere.